# Julia Control Flow Booleans not Working as Expected

Tags: julia

I'm getting results that don't match my expectations when using short-circuit evaluation control flow. This is what I want to do:

```
if var1 || var2 && var3
 do something cool
end
```

instead I get this:

```
if var1 || var2 
 do something that I don't want
end
```

this seems to only evaluate var1 || var2 and skips the && part. I think this should work so, what am I missing?

link to control-flow:
http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/control-flow/

Thanks

The solution, as provided below, shows that I should've used parenthesis to get what I want:

```
  if (var1 || var2) && var3
     do something cool
    end
```

Comment: In english: if var1 or var2 and var3 then do something. But what I get is if var1 or var2 do something. Basically julia is not evaluating the && var3 part, when combined with the or boolean (||). Is that clear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&&` operator has higher precedence than `||` which means your test is equivalent to `var1 || (var2 && var3)` rather than `(var1 || var2) && var3` which may be what you expect. This precedence is standard in many languages, including C, Java, Perl, and Ruby.